# curl_error (Resource id #6) in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am getting a "curl_error (Resource id #6)" while retriving data from a webhook and I am not sure how to solve it. As issue, I am not able to get target ["text"] at RAW body. Follows the code:

```
    <?php
    //Get post data from webhook.
    $webhookResponse = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 

    //Retrieving {"id"} from the data object, via the id property.
    $messageId = $webhookResponse["data"]["id"];
    echo "$messageId";

    $curl = curl_init(); //Starting handle.

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mysite.com/v1/messages/" . $messageId,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true, 
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, 
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, 
      CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT => 2, 
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "authorization: Bearer XEtY2M3Ni00MTNhLWI3NDYtODdjx",
          "cache-control: no-cache",
          "content-type: application/json"
        ),
      ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      echo "curl_error($curl)"; 
      curl_close($curl); //Closing handle

    //Retriving 'text'
    $idText = ["text"];
    echo "$idText";
?>
```

And follows the RAW body retrieved (200 OK):

```
    Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL01FU1NBR0UvZTg4
    {
      "id":"E4ODAtZWM1My0xMWU1LTkyMjctNWYxMjZjZW",
      "roomId":"ZWMxNS0xMWU1LWI5YmQtNjE0ODFmYmE4YWU1",
      "text":"Hello World!",
      "personId":"T1BMRS84MTE3NGUzOC04N2MwLTRmYzUtOTNl",
      "personEmail":"myself@mysite.com",
      "created":"2016-03-17T15:21:23.208Z"
    }
    curl_error(Resource id #6)
```

Any help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a thing:

```
//Retriving 'text'
$idText = ["text"];
echo "$idText";
```

You want to get your response (json) and decode it:

```
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $response = json_decode($response);
  $idText = $response->text;
```

Comment: I applied your suggestion, however, I'm still not getting the 'text' content and still getting error 'Resource id #6'. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank: If you want to see check if there's a curl error,  `var_dump($curl)` and not echo

Comment: I could solve the problem. Many thanks for your usefull help. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was caused by $data as it is an array. So, 'json_encode' is applied in order to convert $data to JSON:

```
$data = array("abc"=> $abc, "def"=> $def, "ghi"=> $ghi);

    $curl = curl_init(); //Starting handle.
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.otherwebsite.com/1.0/sessions?action=action",
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data), //converting $data to JSON.
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "accept: application/json",
          "content-type: application/json"
      ),
    ));

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    error_log("POST JSON Request Body: ".$resp);
    curl_close($curl); //Closing handle

    ?>
```